# Calculation working in Unity Editor but not on my iPhone (comma vs. dot in float)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am doing this calculation:

```
void TESTINGtesting()
{
    string aa = "33,9";
    //float a1 = float.Parse(aa, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
    txt_Slask.text = "(" + aa.ToString() + ") - ";

    float a1 = float.Parse(aa.Replace(',', '.'));

    print("a1: " + a1);

    txt_Slask.text += "++>(";
    txt_Slask.text += a1.ToString();
    txt_Slask.text += ")";
    txt_Slask.text += "<++";
}
```

I get the following result in the Editor:

[image]

And the following result when I upload to my iPhone:

[image]

What I am doing is this:

1. Read in a string with the following format "33.9" (dot)
2. I am reading the file and the number that comes out is "33,9" (comma) -
3. As a backup I am trying to convert the "33,9" to "33.9"
4. When I use the attached code on Editor all is OK but nothing comes up in the UI Text in the iPhone

I have tried with "InvariantCulture" but with the same result.

BTW, my iPhone is Swedish region.

I am puzzled and have not been able to find a solution.

Comment: `aa.Replace(',', '.')` are you sure about doing this? If I remember correctly `float.Parse` parses the input string based on the devices locale settings, so this replacement may break the parsing (which should throw an exception, but perhaps the Unity runtime on iPhone hides that from you)

Comment: No I am not I am afraid, it is part of the testing I am doing. I am aware about the locale but do not know how to fix it so it works with all locale, if that is the problem.

Comment: The obvious first question you have to answer is where the input comes from that is in a different input locale than your application expects. In the code example it is hard coded, but where would it come from in practice?

Comment: The original input file looks like this: (-8.7, 1.0, -3.2)
(0.0, -0.9, 0.0, -0.4)
(-3.9, 1.0, 8.3)
(-0.4, 0.4, 0.6, -0.6)
(-8.8, 1.0, -0.1)
(0.3, 0.3, 0.6, 0.6)
(-6.2, 1.0, 0.8)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
(-4.0, 1.0, 6.0)
(0.5, -0.5, 0.5, -0.5)
(-6.9, 1.0, 3.0)
(0.7, -0.7, 0.2, -0.2) ...and I did recon the problem as all the dots became commas also when reading the file. It's here the real problem is I assume.

Comment: Indeed you should try to find what causes these changes to happen. "Hacking" a string to turn the number into a floating point representation you expect is only going to cover up the real issue (and could lead to more problems later on)

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be dancing around culture and what you're expecting out of the wrong culture.

Let's start with your commented out code, I'm assuming that's an earlier attempt that (predictably) failed:

```
string aa = "33,9";
float a1 = float.Parse(aa, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.NumberFormat);
```

The invariant culture in .Net is `en-us`, and your number in that culture would be represented as `33.9`, not `33,9`. And so your conversion fails.

Then you threw things at the compiler until you finally got the result you want:

```
float.Parse(aa.Replace(',', '.'))
```

However, if you enable the C# static analysis package, you'll get a warning on that line saying that you need to pass the culture to the function, because strings get converted differently to numbers in different cultures.

Specifically, you mentioned your phone is under a Swedish culture, which expects a comma as a decimal separator, which you are thoughtlessly replacing with the line above.

What happens next is up to your framework. I'm assuming an exception is generated and it's ignored, but your stack is unwound, so the rest of your function doesn't run anymore.

Long story short, stick to a specific culture for string representations of numbers in code (invariant is fine), and whenever you do the conversion of these strings, use the correct culture.

```
string aa = "33.9";
float a1 = float.Parse(aa, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems I finally solved the problem so thank you for help.

```
void TESTINGtesting()
{
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");

    string aa = "33,9";

    txt_Slask.text = "B(" + aa.ToString() + ") - ";

    aa = aa.Replace(',', '.');
    float a1 = float.Parse(aa); 

    txt_Slask.text += "++>(";
    txt_Slask.text += a1.ToString();
    txt_Slask.text += ")";
    txt_Slask.text += "<++";
}
```